# Catching error on celery group, instead of individual task

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

Is it possible to error handling on celery group? instead of using error handle on task individually? I tried `on_error` method. But when my task appended in `group` how can I handle specific group element error?

I tried using `chord` but when the error occurred chord's callback won't be called. So how can I handle this error?

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is to make a chain with your group, and a task that will go through results of the group, and do appropriate action(s)...

Comment: @DejanLekic oh, even chain does have one member ? like `chain(grouped_tasks.si()).on_error(log_error.s())`